# How to increase spacing between lines in UITextView

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4, uitextview

How to increase spacing between lines in UITextView?

I wish to use default system font,i.e., Helvetica with size 15.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to control the line spacing in UILabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494498/how-to-control-the-line-spacing-in-uilabel)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277551/iphone-uitextview-set-line-spacing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760924/set-line-height-in-uitextview

Comment: so in short, I cannot do it as the other topics suggest.

Comment: You can definitely do this.  Please accept an answer or submit your solution.

Comment: @nitz19arg please accept my answer below (you can do so by selecting the check mark under the upvote/downvote icons) if it worked for you, or submit your solution.  It's not good etiquette to leave answers hanging..

Answer (score 9):

Declare you implement the protocol by adding

`<NSLayoutManagerDelegate>`

to your interface.  Then, set:

`yourTextView.layoutManager.delegate = self;`

Then override this delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)layoutManager:(NSLayoutManager *)layoutManager lineSpacingAfterGlyphAtIndex:(NSUInteger)glyphIndex withProposedLineFragmentRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    return 5; // Line spacing of 19 is roughly equivalent to 5 here.
}
```

UPDATE: 
I recently discovered that this can also be done using the `NSMutableParagraphStyle setLineSpacing:` API.

In an effort to always provide useful copy-paste code-snippet awesomeness, here you go!

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *myStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[myStyle setLineSpacing:myLineSpacingInt];
[myString addAttribute:myDesiredAttribute value:myStyle range:myDesiredRange];
[myViewElement setAttributedText:myString];
```

^`myViewElement` can be a `UITextField`, `UILabel`, or `UITextView`.

Answer (score 5):

In IOS6+ you can set the typing attributes for a UITextView

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle setLineSpacing:lineSpacing];

NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:paragraphStyle forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];

[textView setTypingAttributes:attrsDictionary];
```